# Cannot fire my action from the container page, props undefined error

Tags: reactjs, redux-form

I am getting  “TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined”
 when i try to fire my function onChange from a deeper component. I can fire the action from the DemoForm component, but then I cannot pass in my value as it becomes undefined so, I am trying to make a function that takes in the event information and then I am firing my action but it says  props is undefined, when I do a debugger and check on the console, its all there

```
// App.js

class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props)
      }

      handleThis(e){
        this.props.SomeAction 
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <DemoForm state={this.props} someFunction={this.handleThis }/>
            <AnotherForm/>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    const mapStateToProps = (reduxState) => {
      return reduxState;
    }

    const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
      return bindActionCreators(actionCreators, dispatch);
    }

    export default connect(
      mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps
    )(App)


 // Demo.js 

    let DemoForm = ({ handleSubmit, submitting, state }) =>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(showResults)}>
            <Field name="value" label="Value" component={RenderInput} onChange={(e) => this.props.someFunction(e.target.value) } />


            <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
    {console.log("Demo state >>>>> ", {state})}
        </form>



    DemoForm = reduxForm({
        form: 'demo',
        destroyOnUnmount: false,
        validate
    })(DemoForm)

    export default DemoForm 


 // RenderInput

    const RenderInput = createRenderer((input, label, onChange) => {
        return <input {...input}/>
    })

    export default RenderInput


// createRenderer

    const createRenderer = render => ({ input, meta, label, ...rest }) => {
        return (
            <div>
                {/* <pre> {JSON.stringify(input, null, 2) }</pre> */}
                <label> {label}</label>
                {render(input, label, rest)}
                {
                    meta.touched &&
                    <span className="text-danger"> {meta.error} </span>
                }
            </div>
        )
    }

    export default createRenderer


// REDUCER  
            const initialState = {
                todos: [],
                count: 0,
                demoPercent: 0,
                anotherPercent : 0
            }

            export default function rootReducer(state = initialState, action) {
                if(action.type === "INC"){
                    console.log("incrementing count")
                    let newState = {...state}
                    newState.count++
                    return {
                        ...newState
                    }
                }
                if(action.type === "GET_PERCENT"){
                    console.log("getting balance percent", action.payload)
                    let newState = {...state}
                    newState.demoPercent = action.payload;
                    newState.anotherPercent = 100 - action.payload;
                    return {
                        ...newState
                    }
                }
                return state;
            }


    // ACTION

            export function increase(){
                console.log("i am INC action firing")
                return {
                    type: "INC"
                }
            }

            export function getPercent(value){
       console.log(value)  //value is undefined
                return {
                    type: "GET_PERCENT",
                    paypoad : value
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the handler in your controller, to do that just change your App component constructor to:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.handleThis = this.handleThis.bind(this);
}
```

Comment: the action is firing, but the dispatch is finding the payload as "undefined" ???? I want the handleThis to fire the action and dispatch reducer as in the code

Answer (score 1):

You have to bind your function... And the best way to bind function is to use `arrow` functions

```
render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <DemoForm state={this.props} someFunction={(e) => this.handleThis(e)}/>
            <AnotherForm/>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```